# make own logout button & redirect after login

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-sdk-3.0

I made so I can login to Facebook by pressing the loginbutton.
Just write in my user-name and password and it will log me in.

After that I have been logged in, it will take me back to the same Activity and with a blue Logout button.

Im going to build a navigator-drawer or actionbar, and THERE I will make an own logout button that logs me out from Facebook. In other words, I dont want the blue logout button.

Also, where can I redirect to another Activity after logging in?

So to be clear:

1. After logging in to Facebook, there will be no blue LogOut button, it will instead be a button in actionbar that is says logout and that button will log me out (how to, and what to delete in the code?)
2. After that I have logged in, I will redirect to a new Activity (how to..?)
   Here is my code:

---

```
public class SocialLoginFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_social_login, container,
            false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("name", "user_birthday",
            "friends_birthday"));

    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

And here is the other code:

```
public class SocialLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private SocialLoginFragment socialLoginFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        socialLoginFragment = new SocialLoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, socialLoginFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        socialLoginFragment = (SocialLoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**:

I don't now if my problem/question was good written, will try again.

1. My Login to Facebook button are in the middle of my Activity, and thats fine.
   After that I login with the button, the button will change to LogOut.
   The thing is that I will have an ActionBar or make my own button and put it in the Navigator-Drawer, so therefore, I dont need the blue LogOut button, I will delete it and put what LogOut button do in another button that I made.. (How do I delete the Logout button without delete the Login button, and how do I make a new button that will logout from Facebook)
2. After that I logged in, I will come back to the same Activity, what I want to do is to send me to a new Activity, not the same Activity, in that way, the LogOut button will be gone?

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is your question or problem?

Comment: @PeriHartman
I updated my questions with an EDIT, that you will see here, maybe my questions are better written. Try to read and see if you understand what I mean .. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you don't need to delete the buttons, just hide them.

To hide or show buttons, do something like this:

```
findViewById (R.id.login_button).setVisibility (View.GONE); // hides button
```

or

```
button.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Will try this. Thank you.
`if (state.isOpened()) {
        findViewById (R.id.login_button).setVisibility (View.GONE);`

The question will be, how take the button back in an actionbar or a navigator-drawer.. Will try little more, will come back with answers if I fix this.

Comment: Didnt work to do that... will see if I find where to put the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how take the button back".  Do you mean "make the button visible again"?

Comment: This is what I mean. When you press the Login to Facebook button and login, you will be redirected to the SAME Activity after the login. What I need is to get redirected to a NEW Activity that I made, in that way the Logout button will be gone.

Or like this. You login with the button, after you login, the button will change from "Login to facebook" to "Logout" and the button is blue. I want to make an Navigator Drawer and put the Logout Button there. http://wpandroid.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/wordpress-for-android-version-2-3-menu-drawer-on-samsung-galaxy-s3-update.jpg Or in an actionbar.

Comment: In one way yes, make the LOGOUT button invisible, or in best way, move it to the actionbar or the navigation drawer.
Now what happens is that the button just change name from Login to Facebook to Logout. Most important thing is to REDIRECT after I login to an new Activity.

Comment: So, when you create the activity, all you need to do is show one of the buttons and hide the other.  Correct?  In order to do that you would need to know whether the user is logged into facebook or not, right?

Comment: I did a new EDIT with 2 pictures, go up on this site and look at the pictures, then you will understand what I mean.

Comment: It's difficult to answer because you are unsure of what you are asking.  Part of that, understandably, is lack of knowledge.  The other part is having several design options, which makes the situation more complicated.  Pick a design option and you can evolve it later.  To answer your specific question about how to keep one button and delete the other, I recommend my original suggestion: have two buttons; hide one and make the other visible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41484/discussion-between-peri-hartman-and-dmt82)

Answer (score 0):

When the state is changed and you verify if the session is opened, you can create an intent to call your activity.

```
if (state.isOpened()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivityYouMade.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```